# How to update the log level of passenger?

Tags: nginx, meteor, passenger

I have been trying to figure out how to set the passenger_log_level to 7 in passenger+nginx configuration on Ubuntu 18.04 server. I tried to set it inside Nginx configuration for the server block but it is not allowed there. Please guide me how can I update the log level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update the log level of the Passenger in Nginx + Passenger configuration, set

```
passenger_log_level Number(0-7);
```

in the http context.

On Ubuntu, open the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file and look for http context and set the

```
passenger_log_level 7;
```